# laravel nova confirm box

Tags: laravel, validation

is there a way to display a confirm box in laravel/ laravel nova if the user changes a certain field?

for example, he changes the field name in the update form, when pressing save a query should come up, you have changed the field name, are you sure?

Thanks for your help